# How to bind checkbox values to a null object in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to store all the selected checkbox items in a property.

This is a 'generic' property in one of my object models, it holds all different types of data.

This property is initialized as null, so Vue doesn't understand that it's supposed to be an array. So it only ever binds one checkbox value to this property.

When I initialize this property using [] to declare it as array, it works as intended. However the objects are passed down externally as JSON so initializing them as array is not an option.

```
var working = new Vue({
    el: "#a",
    data: {
        options: ["Apple", "Banana", "Citrus"],
        answers: [], //<- I'm unable to do this in my scenario
    }
});

var notWorking = new Vue({
    el: "#b",
    data: {
        options: ["Apple", "Banana", "Citrus"],
        answers: null 
    }
});
```

Here is a quick JSfiddle I made showcasing what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/ojvfy39p/12/

What adjustments must I make to the "Non working example" to achieve what the "Working example" does? I'

Comment: Even if you get the objects externally couldn't you simply modify them to the proper data structure before setting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `v-model` you could use a event to trigger a method.

```js
var working = new Vue({
    el: "#a",
    data: {
     options: ["Apple", "Banana", "Citrus"],
     answers: [], //<- I'm unable to do this in my scenario
    }
});

var notWorking = new Vue({
    el: "#b",
    data: {
     options: ["Apple", "Banana", "Citrus"],
     answers: null 
    },
    methods: {
     updateAnswers(val) {
        if(this.answers === null) {
          this.answers = [val];
        } else if(this.answers.indexOf(val) > -1) {
          this.answers.splice(this.answers.indexOf(val), 1);
        } else {
          this.answers = [...this.answers, val];
        }
      },
    }
});

console.clear();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

Working example. "Answers" initialized as array.
<form id="a">
<div v-for="(option,i) in options">
  <input type="checkbox" :value="option" name="option" v-model="answers"/> {{ option }}
</div>
  <br>
  Selected items: {{ answers }}
</form>
<br>

Not working example, "Answers" initialized as null
<form id="b">
<div v-for="option in options">
  <input type="checkbox" :value="option" name="option" @click="updateAnswers(option)" /> {{ option }}
</div>
  <br>
  Selected items: {{ answers }}
</form>
```